# Uiview to Data (Saving a Gif to firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, animated-gif

In my app, I take a photo from my camera, and then the user can add a sticker gif on it.
I want to save the result on Firebase Storage (in a gif format)

So to summarize, I want to convert my UIview into Data, to save it on Firebase ( `Storage.storage().reference().child("Gif").putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in })`

I have tried that :

```
 let yourViewToData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.canvasView)
```

but the result isn't a gif file

I have tried a func like this but I cannot intercept Data on it and I'm not sure of the result :

```
  let img = self.canvasView.toImage()


animatedGif(from: [img])

func animatedGif(from images: [UIImage]) {
        let fileProperties: CFDictionary = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]  as CFDictionary
        let frameProperties: CFDictionary = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String): 1.0]] as CFDictionary

        let documentsDirectoryURL: URL? = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileURL: URL? = documentsDirectoryURL?.appendingPathComponent("animated.gif")

        if let url = fileURL as CFURL? {
            if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, images.count, nil) {
                CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)
                for image in images {
                    if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
                        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, frameProperties)
                    }
                }
                if !CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) {
                    print("Failed to finalize the image destination")
                }
                print("Url = \(fileURL)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea how I can save my UIView to a gif file on Firebase Storage?

I am looking to make an alternative solution . Take like 15 screenshot of UImage from my UIView, in order to make a gif later. I have this func :

```
func toImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
    self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImageFromMyView!
}
```

Does someone know how can I make like 15 screenshot with this func? Thanks

Thanks !

Comment: maybe with : NSData(contentsOf: URL) ? With a escaping on my func ?

Comment: I am looking to make an alternative solution . Take like 15 screenshot of UImage from my UIView, in order to make a gif later. I have this func :
func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImageFromMyView!
    }
Does someone know how can I make like 15 screenshot with this func?

Thanks